# water level in a tank

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I am trying to develop a relationship that can give the area fraction of a circle that contains water, as a function of the water level, (h)

Say I have a unit circle $1-x^2-y^2$ and set the bounds from $-1$ to $1$ on the x-axis and -1 to h on the y-axis and perform a double integration.

> Will this work somehow? I'm not having much luck

Any tips are greatly appreciated!

Comment: A circle or a sphere ?

Comment: Or is the figure a cone? Either way, you need a 3D aspect for this problem.

Comment: circle. it will actually be a cylinder lying down in the end but I would hope to simply multiply the area fraction by the desired length to get the volume

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do a double integral for this (unless you really want to).  If you're trying to find the area defined by a straight line and a section of a circle, it can be done with geometry.

For circle of radius $r$, and height of water $h$, consider the triangle you get defined by the level of the water and center of the circle.  The angle at the centre can be found $\alpha = 2 \cos^{-1}\left(1-\tfrac hr\right)$.  The area of interest is the difference between the area of the section of the circle, and the triangle, so
$$ \Delta = \pi r^2 \frac{\alpha}{2\pi} - \frac 12 r^2 \sin(\alpha) = \frac{r^2}{2} \left[\alpha - \sin\alpha\right].$$

Comment: thank you. yes I was shown how to do it with triangles but I know integration is a much more powerful method and I'm trying to get really familiar with it. So yes, I do really want to use integration...